# Angular 2 localhost and Backendserver Connection

Tags: angular, http, networking, server

I am trying to run a Angular 2 project with npm start on my machine and access the backend on another server. 
When I call a post or get I always getting the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing' error in the Firefox console.
When I deploy my app on the server it works perfectly fine, but I dont want to wait all the time to deploy my app.

I tried different solutions, like proxies. Do I need to configure my localhost or something else? Is there a state of the art solution?

Comment: Which language used to develop backend ?? Node js or else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up proxy in your local environment.

In your `package.json` add in the script `"serve-dev": "<startApplication> --sourcemap=false --proxy-config proxy.config.json"`.

And run it using `npm run serve-dev`.

And `proxy.config.json` file should look like this:

```
{
  "/api/*":{
    "target":"http://localhost:5005",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

And when you call endpoint in your service just `get` should be like: `this._http.get('./api/myEndpoint')`.

Answer (score 0):

Set this up before you API route and after your app use

```
app.use(express.static(publicPath)); // Set the path for express to use

// Add headers
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});
```