# Deployed Angular 2 on Webserver throws status 0 on get

Tags: node.js, angular, get, web-deployment, polyfills

Thanks for the help, in advance.

I have developed a Angular 2 Single-Page Application and build it with `ng build`. I moved the builded stuff onto a webserver, on which a node.js backend is running on the port `4000`. If you go to the main page, I try to get something from the backend with:

```html
    return this.http
      .get("https://localhost:4000/auto")
      .toPromise()
      .then( (res)=> res.json());
```

But then I get this error message:

error message:
[image]

It does work if I change localhost to the ip Address of the webserver, but only if cross-origin is allowed in the backend, which I would like to have disabled.

A thing to note is, that I am also using https (ssl certificate) for the first time, so maybe there is something wrong ?

This is my first time deploying something to a real webserver, so I am not sure what is wrong. Everything else seems to work with the build, only got that problem, communicating with the backend on the same webserver (Webserver runs apache). I hope someone can help me. I hope i explained everything necessary, if you need more informations, tell me what you need.

Comment: >"But then i get this error message:" and what is that?

Comment: Sorry if that is not indicated. The error message is the part below "GET https://localhost:4000/auto 0 () .. .. polyfills.9631ae86c1f2c6c270fd.bundle.js:1" I shall post it as screenshot

Comment: @Iancovici so I should use the ip adress of the server, instead of localhost ? Even when the backend is on the same server ?

Comment: does https://localhost:4000/auto show you json in the browser?

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra  no, there is only that error message. It does no even reach the backend on port 4000 (nothing logged in console of the running backend)

Comment: I mean if you type in the backend url in the browser, without using angular to retrieve the data

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra ah, sorry. Misunderstood that. Yes when i type in the url: https:// address:4000/auto  in the browser, i get a empty array (which is like it should be) and the backend throws a status 200 in console. So everything there should be fine. (But could onlywork right now, because cross origin is on? not sure)

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but could you try http.get<Array<any>>("https://localhost:4000/auto") and subscribe or use the async pipe to show the data.

Comment: @Marcel Hoekstra. I will try that, but I think the GET works, as it worked with cross origin usage.

Comment: You are right, won't have anything todo with your code. Did you find a solution yet. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451200/angular-2-localhost-and-backendserver-connection