# CORS error with PayPal Rest API, firebase functions and Angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase, paypal, cors, angular6

I would like to set up a payment for my marketplace with Paypal. I build my app with Angular 6, and the backend with firebase, using firebase functions (google cloud functions).

I used this [Paypal firebase function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/paypal) example to build my firebase backend.

In my frontEnd app I got this function to trigger the payment method:

```
processPayment() {
    this.http.post('https://us-central1-project.cloudfunctions.net/pay', {price: this.amount })
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

So this should redirect me to the paypal page for the payment of the `amount` variable. Here's where the `CORS` error happend, when I triggered the function I end up with this error in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://us-central1-project.cloudfunctions.net/pay (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://us-central1-project.cloudfunctions.net/pay. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this error comes from the fact that I'm trying to access this page with my IP through localhost:4200. (Notice that the page is working if i make the request to https://us-central1-cop-room-host.cloudfunctions.net/pay manually).

So I tried to modify my Cloud function code, I added:

```
const cors = require('cors')({
  origin: true,
});
```

However, I end up with this error in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-54G25913XT5841335. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-54G25913XT5841335. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

Furthermore, origin:true is unsafe...

How can I configure this payment method in order to make it work with angular 6 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To be clear, this is not an Angular error. It afflicts all web apps equally, and most of the fixes we’ll look at below are actually modifying the server or the browser.**

> You’ve run a foul of the Same Origin Policy – it says that every AJAX
>   request must match the exact host, protocol, and port of your site.
>   Things that might cause this:
>
> Hitting a server from a locally-served file (a request from
>   file:///YourApp/index.html to http://api.awesome.com) Hitting an
>   external API (a request from http://yourapp.com to
>   http://api.awesome.com). Hitting an internal API (a request from
>   http://yourapp.com to http://api.yourapp.com). Hitting a different
>   port on the same host (webapp is on http://localhost:3000, API is
>   http://localhost:4000) Requesting over http from https or vice-versa
>   (requesting https://yourapp.com from http://yourapp.com)

Comment: I see what you mean and I think I understand the problem. So In my case I'm requesting from localhost:4200 to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-54G25913XT5841335 if I understand the problem correctly. But I don't understand what should I do to make it work ?

Comment: if you want to make it work you have to use https://localhost.com:4200 instead of http://localhost.com:4200 and if you want to create https://localhost check this link https://brianflove.com/2016/10/22/angular-cli-using-https/

Comment: My api should be located at localhost.com ? I can't achieve this ahah

Comment: yes bcoz paypal using https secured connection our local host using un secured connection i mean http

Comment: I followed the tutorial and connect my browser to https://localhost:4200, but I always end up with the same error...

Comment: check whether the localhost connection is secure or not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451200/angular-2-localhost-and-backendserver-connection  check this brother

Comment: Thanks, but the CORS problem comes from paypal API which I can't touch lol. I found a way to make it work I'll just post it.

Answer (score 0):

CORS errors are complicated to handle in webApps, especially if you do not have access to the API code you're using. So I changed a bit the mecanism of the server, instead of getting a 302 redirection to the paypal page after I triggered the pay function

```
res.redirect(302, links.approval_url.href);
```

I send the link and I access the link directly trought the angular app:

function code (index.ts):

```
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(links['approval_url'].href));
```

Web App component code:

```
processPayment() {
   this.http.post('https://us-central1-cop-room-host.cloudfunctions.net/pay', {price: this.amount })
     .subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
       document.location.href = res;
     });
   }
```